# How to make a view list entities, not translations?

Tags: views, 8

I need to list content entities in their original languages, but views module shows all content translations.

I need something like grouping by entity IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the proper filter is the following:

"Content: Default translation (= True)"

Comment: Your welcome! Can you mark it as the "right" answer, so for people in the future, visiting this thread will have more trust in the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired result by adding the `Translation source (= Not specified)` filter.

The original entity translations have the `Translation source` field empty. And it's pretty safe to use the `Not specified` language because entities using it are untranslatable.